# Scala - type of collection created by cons operators

Tags: scala

What is the type of collection created by cons operator?

```
1::2::Nil
// println((1::2::Nil).getClass)
// class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

"abc"::1::2::Nil
// println(("abc"::1::2::Nil).getClass)
// class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

val x:List[Int] = 1::2::Nil
// println(x.getClass)
// class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

This makes it seem that lists can contain both string and Int at the same time.
However, this has been specifically called out in "Programming in Scala", that list contains homogeneous objects.

> Like lists, tuples are immutable, but unlike lists, tuples can contain
>   different types of elements. Whereas a list might be a List[Int] or a
>   List[String], a tuple could contain both an integer and a string at
>   the same time.

I think at runtime, we see the same types due to type erasure. If that's true, then what is the correct type of the list/collection generated using cons operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out the signature of the `::` (cons) method:

```
def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
  new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

It means, you can prepend any `B` as long as `B` is a supertype of `A` (current type of List elements), and the resulting list will have all elements typed as `B`. So Scala will pick the most common supertype. In this particular case it's gonna be `Any`, which is Scala's root type (similar to `Object` in Java). If you have a more specific common supertype, Scala will try hard to use it instead of `Any`:

```
> class Animal 
> class Cat extends Animal 
> class Dog extends Animal 
> new Cat :: new Cat :: Nil 
res3: List[Cat] = List(ammonite.$sess.cmd1$Cat@2b974137, ammonite.$sess.cmd1$Cat@71734463)
> new Dog :: res3 
res4: List[Animal] = List(ammonite.$sess.cmd2$Dog@79f3f34c, ammonite.$sess.cmd1$Cat@2b974137, ammonite.$sess.cmd1$Cat@71734463)
```

Comment: Ahh.. That makes sense. Scala's type inference is able to find the most common supertype here. Since a new list is being created, we are not constrained with subtypes of the original list's type.

Answer (score 2):

Scala has something called "subytping". The element type of the list will be a common supertype of all the individual element types.

In your first case, the inferred type will be `List[Int]`, in your second case `List[Any]`. It is perfectly legal for both an `Int` and a `String` to be elements of a `List[Any]`, since both are subtypes of `Any` (in fact, *every* type is a subtype of `Any`, because `Any` is the *top type*).

In other words: all elements in your second example *are* of the same type. They are all of type `Any`.